# REGEX: Remove everything except ALL images

Tags: regex

I would like to know how I can use a regex for removing everything EXCEPT all image tags.

I already tried these:

(?s)^[^<]*(.*) -> removes all the text before the img tag

(?s)^([^>]+>).* -> removes all the text after the img tag

Does anybody know how to combine these 2 for multiple images?

Here is an example of the content I want to apply it to:

```
Text text text. <img alt="alt text" src="path/to-image.png" />Text text text. <img alt="alt text" src="path/to-image.png" />Text text text. <img alt="alt text" src="path/to-image.png" />Text text text. <img alt="alt text" src="path/to-image.png" />
```

My desired result should be:

```
<img alt="alt text" src="path/to-image.png" /><img alt="alt text" src="path/to-image.png" /><img alt="alt text" src="path/to-image.png" /><img alt="alt text" src="path/to-image.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example expressions do not work for me. However, turn "removing everything except all image tags" into "extract only image tags" and you can easily get what you want:

```
<img [^>]*\/> <!-- EDIT: XHTML only -->
<img [^>]*\/?> <!-- covers HTML and XHTML -->
```

Try: http://www.regexr.com/3eq09

Comment: `<img src=">>>.png" />`. By the way, it's possible to extract all image tags as they have no closing tag.

Comment: Not `/>` but `/?>`.

Comment: The given example was in XHTML, so it seems just appropriate to me to confine the expression to it, which could also be helpful to refine the expression when dealing with ">" in attribute values.

Comment: Seems like for xhtml it's ok. But I don't see any reasons for thinking that question is about xhtml.

Comment: The example code has <img/> instead of <img>. Sure, to generalize it for both HTML and XHTML it would be appropriate to use <img [^>]*\/?>. I added this to the solution.

Comment: Html5 allows closing _some_ tags with `/>`. Many IDE are automatically substituting `/>` for such tags. Most people are using html and almost noone uses xhtml. It would be strange not to say about xhtml if it is. And img is not a reason to tell it's xhtml.

Comment: Ok, I can agree to that.